# Why does my mapped drive not appear on client machine?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I am trying to create a GPO to map a drive to a security group:

[image]

When I sign into the client machine and do `gpresult -r`, I see that `Drive Mapping` was successfully applied. However, I don't see the mapped drive.

I have made sure of the following:

- The UNC path of the folder to map is correct.
- The user I'm signed into on the client machine is present in security filtering.
- The GPO link is enabled.
- The update was forced with `gpupdate/force`.
- The user I'm logged in as on the client machine is a member of `Contractors`.

Also note the GPO is linked at domain level.

Why is the mapped drive not appearing on the client machine?

Comment: Does it works if you remove the item-level targeting ?

Answer (score 0):

By default GPP runs under the SYSTEM account context, which doesn't have permissions on the network share. You need to set the option to **Run in logged-on user's security context** in the GPP.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772371(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_Run

Comment: I have enabled this setting but haven't had any change.

Comment: Change the action to Replace and make sure the user in questions has appropriate NTFS permissions on the shared folder.